# Cancancan nested resource authorization fails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan, mongoid4

Simply I explain it [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/248). The question is how can I authorize nested resource with mongoid? Suppose that I have a `Project` model and a `Project::Task` model. `Project` has many `Project::Task`. I want to authorize `Project::Task` on controller level and do not want to show another `Project`'s task. So basically I do below to handle it:

`load_and_authorize_resource :project, class: Project
load_and_authorize_resource :task, through: :project_id, class: Project::Task`

But this does not work. It always throws 403. What is the proper way to do this?